# How to make sure that my Nvidia graphics card drive was updated?

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I have installed Ubuntu recently but I coulnd't use the driver which I downloaded from Nvidia's official page and I am not sure it would be better if I was able to install it. I would like to ask how can I make sure my graphics card driver was updated somewhat by Ubuntu  via Internet..

my card is Nvidia GeForce 210M

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can update with the following commands

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

---

You can verify your install by pressing the super key and typing

```
nvidia x server settings
```

Open that